# Need to change a shell command into groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I've managed to get what docker images have been deployed but it has to be written in groovy.

I have the following:

```
sh script: '''
    export PATH=\"$PATH\":\"${WORKSPACE}\"         
 
    for docker-image in interface data keycloak artifactory ; do
      DOCKERHOST=`echo ${DOCKERURL}/images-rancher/$docker-image | sed 's!^localhost://!!g'`
      DOCKERVERSION=`docker image ls ${DOCKERHOST} --format '{{ json .Tag }}' | head -1`
      echo "${DOCKERHOST} - ${DOCKERVERSION}"
    done
'''
```

Changing it into groovy:

```
def image = [ "interface", "data" , "keycloak", "artifactory" ]
.
.
.
for docker-image in image
   println docker-image
```

How would you put that in a groovy script?

Thanks

Comment: The first is already in Groovy. If you wanted it in pure Groovy without any `sh` steps, that's not possible, since you can't do `docker image ls` directly in Groovy (unless there is some Jenkins plugin for doing that I don't know about).

Comment: I really want everything in groovy apart from the `docker image ls` which I know would have to be done via `sh`.  

How would I call `docker-image` in the for loop?

Easily done in shell script but I cant get it to work in groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get most of the way to using Groovy instead of bash. The `doRegexManipulation()` function is left as an exercise for you to implement.

Note that the `docker image ls` [`sh` step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) is still required, and cannot be translated to "pure" Groovy.

```
withEnv(["PATH=${env.PATH}:${env.WORKSPACE}"]) {
    def images = [ "interface", "data" , "keycloak", "artifactory" ]

    for (String docker_image : images) {
        def DOCKERHOST = doRegexManipulation("${DOCKERURL}/images-rancher/$docker_image")
        def DOCKERVERSION = sh(
            script: """docker image ls '${DOCKERHOST}' --format '{{ json .Tag }}' | head -1""",
            returnStdout: true,
        )
        echo "${DOCKERHOST} - ${DOCKERVERSION}"
    }​
}
```

If you wanted to, you can go one step further and replace the `head -1` part with Groovy code, since that can be done in Groovy as well.

The `withEnv` step is documented [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables). It is used to set environment variables for a block of Groovy code, thereby making those environment variables available to any child processes spawned in the block of Groovy code.